# How can I orient a list item to the right side of its parent unordered list/div?

Tags: html, css

So basically, I have a menu at the top of my page:

```
| Menu 1 | Menu 2 | Menu 3 | Menu 4 |
                             Menu 4 Item 1
                             Menu 4 Item 2
                             Menu 4 Item 3
```

But I want to orient the last menu so that the menu items do not extend pass the screen, but instead expand backwards, such as:

```
| Menu 1 | Menu 2 | Menu 3 | Menu 4 |
                      Menu 4 Item 1
                      Menu 4 Item 2
                      Menu 4 Item 3
```

Maybe I'm just not searching the right keywords, but I can't figure out how to do this. Here is the code:

```
<div style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #383aff; clear: both; font-size: 13px; height: 36px; margin: auto; width: 100%;">
<ul style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<li>Menu Item 4 <ul style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index: 100;">
<li><a style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
<li><a style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
<li><a style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">Long Submenu Item ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF</a></li></ul></li>
<li>Menu Item 2</li>
<li>Menu Item 2</li>
<li>Menu Item 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899351/make-an-li-element-stretch-wider-than-the-containing-ul) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186259/horizontal-menu-ul-align-right-and-align-left) questions are similar, but not solutions.

Comment: Do you have any code we can see at all?

Comment: It's quite easy, but as said, a demo is needed. Essentially, your dropdown is currently set to something like `left: 0` and you can just change that to `right: 0;`.

Comment: The code is generated by a webapp in our corporate intranet, so I'll scrub the result and post it.

Comment: The code has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

http://jsfiddle.net/mn6pj79L/

This only changes the last child of the mainmenu items

```
ul {
    width: 400px;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1px;
    margin-left: -3px;
}

ul li { 
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: silver;
}

ul li ul {
    width: 150px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul li ul li {
    width: 150px;
}

ul li:last-child ul {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Does it work on all major browsers? It displays weird on Firefox: http://imgur.com/twgnT1H